# Pass values to AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm developing an android app and I'm kinda stuck on this issue, and that I can not pass a variable AsyncTask correctly. Is that moving from the main series of the form execute (value), but i dont know how taking that value inside the AsyncTask (doInBackground).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**String... urls** this is your method parameter.

**Excute** runs doInBackground method and yu can pass them like below

**new Conexion().Execute("tip","tip1"...)**

then you can use it in doInBackground

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> categoria = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    categoria.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipo", urls[0]));
    categoria.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipo1", urls[1]));
    .
    .
```

Comment: how can i pass only 1 string?

Comment: new Conexion().Execute("tip")** you put a string to urls array. then categoria.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipo", urls[0]));

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor of your asyncTask and pass your value in constructor

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a new `Object` (i.e. `AsyncTaskParameters`) that has getters and setters for all info you want to serve?

You would get something like:
`public class Conexion extends AsyncTask<AsyncTaskParameters, Void, JSONArray>`